# jq - JSON convert keys into objects

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to reformat a big JSON from an Excel to JSON conversion into a valid JSON for import.
In my research I came across jq and hope some one more deep into can help me.

I have an Array of Employees like this one

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "birthday": "1990-01-01",
      "account": "true",
      "address.street": "Street",
      "address.addition": "1",
      "address.zipCode": "1000",
      "address.city": "Vienna",
      "address.region": "AT",
      "contactDetails.1.phone": "+431234567",
      "contactDetails.1.mail": "first.last@mail.com",
      "organisations.0.id": 1,
      "departments.0.id": 1,
      "roles.0.id": 1
    },
  ]
}
```

the output should look as follows for each Employee

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "birthday": "1990-01-01",
      "account": "true",
      "address": {
        "street": "Street",
        "addition": "1",
        "zipCode": "1000",
        "city": "Vienna",
        "region": "AT"
      },
      "contactDetails": [
        {
          "phone": "",
          "mail": ""
        },
        {
          "phone": "+431234567",
          "mail": "first.last@mail.com"
        }
      ],
      "organisations": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ],
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ],
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

is this possible with jq or any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Probably simpler to do with a quick JavaScript or Python script. Example [here](https://medium.com/agileactors/json-to-json-transformation-a-pragmatic-approach-c2c5e5a32636).

Comment: thank you, will surely help others too. but the two solutions provided are nice, since you can do it on jqplay.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using `to_entries` to access keys and values. The `.key` is split at dots using `/`, the parts looking like numbers converted to numbers representing array indices, and used as path to set the `.value` with `setpath`. Using a `reduce` iteration successively builds up the result objects, for each item in the `.Employees` array. The only caveat is that the zeroth item in the `.contactDetails` array (unaddressed in the input data, but necessary to include higher indices) is not automatically populated with the keys of its sibling item (and empty string values, i.e. `{"phone": "", "mail": ""}`) which you would have to provide separately.

```bash
.Employees[] |= (
  reduce to_entries[] as $e (null;
    setpath($e.key / "." | map(tonumber? // .); $e.value)
  )
)
```

```json
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "birthday": "1990-01-01",
      "account": "true",
      "address": {
        "street": "Street",
        "addition": "1",
        "zipCode": "1000",
        "city": "Vienna",
        "region": "AT"
      },
      "contactDetails": [
        null,
        {
          "phone": "+431234567",
          "mail": "first.last@mail.com"
        }
      ],
      "organisations": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ],
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ],
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i8bCSKGJns-)

Comment: yes, the 0 index in the contactDetails array got ignored by Excel to JSON conversion since both columns have been empty, maybe should have put some space value or something.
but that's ok, now I can just find and replace "null" with the needed data set

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using [streaming](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#streaming).  Streaming produces an array for each leaf-value. The path (also an array) is the first element in the array and the leaf-value is the second element in the array.  Splitting the *dotted* path elements to produce more path elements creates the structure you are looking for.  After processing the paths, `fromstream` reconstructs the desired JSON output.

N.B.:  Missing array elements produce `null` elements in the output.

```
fromstream(
  tostream
  |[(.[0] | map((splits("\\.")? // .) | (tonumber? // .))), (.[1] // empty)]
)
```

Example output:

```json
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "birthday": "1990-01-01",
      "account": "true",
      "address": {
        "street": "Street",
        "addition": "1",
        "zipCode": "1000",
        "city": "Vienna",
        "region": "AT"
      },
      "contactDetails": [
        null,
        {
          "phone": "+431234567",
          "mail": "first.last@mail.com"
        }
      ],
      "organisations": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ],
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ],
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/c6A5oLvrU5P).

Comment: thank you, I took the first as solution, since it was earlier posted